# Making polygon boundaries of different feature classes coincident?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, snapping, coincident

I have two polygon feature classes:

1. Cadastral layer and
2. another polygon layer "zones".

In both feature classes the polygon boundaries are coincident inside their feature but not between the features.

What I want to do is leave the cadastral layer boundaries fixed and snap the 'zones' layer boundaries to them as close as possible within a distance of 2 metres to remove all the small silvers.

I have tried snapping zones to cadastral with a distance of 2 metres and that worked for some boundaries but not all slivers 2m of less. Why do some boundary lines snap to each other when inside the 2m distance and some do not?

I have also tried integrate where you can rank one class over another and generally it works well for distances 1 metre or less but over 1m can even move the rank 1 class boundaries when snapping the boundaries together which is not suitable.

What tool or combination of tools can I use to snap the boundaries of the different features together when they are within 2 metres of each other and boundaries outside of 2 metres stay as they are?

The only strong rule I want to use is that the cadastral layer boundaries cannot move at all.

Answer (score 1):

You might try running the densify tool first to provide more vertices for the snap. In addition you can try different snap environments. Alternately you could set up a topology and validate it giving priority to your cadastral layer. But use copies or at least do it in an edit session since a 2m tolerance might cause unwanted changes in either or both layers.